# symfony : why i should using twig if i can just write the html code inside the php file?

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

in symfony docs they say you should using twig files to write html code 
but I tried to use this code inside my DefaultController.php inside symfony project

```
            if ($row["THEID"] != 0) {
                ?>
                <span style="color:red" class="UserNameS"> <?php echo $name;?>                  
                </span>
                <?php
                //echo $name;               

            }
```

and thst's worked like any other normal flat php code so can I just write all my code like that or I will get problems when I upload my project on my host ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this will work (even after deployment), but then what's the point of using symfony if you do not use the framework as they recommend? Symfony helps you structure your code with the conventions and recommendations you can find in the documentation. Tools like twig were created to help you develop faster and better, and to make collaboration between developers possible and efficient.

**Twig enforces a clear separation between controller and view**; you have to gather all data in the controller, and pass it to the twig template. Twig will only be able to display it. Twig makes your templates reusable (with the blocks) and helps you format your data (with the filters). But as you can not use php code in twig templates you can not access the database (or do other business logic) your controller is supposed to do.

As a result you are forced to divide your display logic (generating the HTML) and your business logic (gathering & processing data). Your code will automatically become much better and much easier to understand (especially for other developers or you in the future). This is very useful: If you want to change something after two years and have forgotten pretty much everything how exactly you've programmed your application you'll still remember the conventions set up by symfony and chances are very high you can make that change without much hassle. If you would've written it with mixed php/html this is very likely not the case.

So in short: Just trust the documentation of symfony, and try to do everything as recommended. You'll save a lot of time all things considered.

Comment: Additionally, if you like a good read why to use template engines in general and the advantages of twig over other TEs: http://fabien.potencier.org/templating-engines-in-php.html